# What is the basic level of Accessibility for UK local government web site?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, accessibility

I'm designing a new site for a local government department in Scotland and I want to make sure I meet the minimum accessibility level for the site.

I had planned to use some jQuery effects, and also to AJAXify the content.  But I realised all this JavaScript probably won't be accessible.

We will be using VS2008 ASP.NET 3.5 framework. (C# server side and SQL Server 2005 db)

Does anyone know what the min standard would be for a government run site?  It will be public facing and its target user will be kids between 11 and 17.

Also, is there any tools out there for checking our web site?  Built in/Add on tools for Visual Studio would be great.

We normally design in house site for our administration teams, so this is the first time we've had to worry about accessibility so answer in a "For Dummies" style if you want! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be a question for the client?

Comment: That was the clients answer.  They are small dept and don't have any IT knowledge, and they are looking to keep themselves right...but leaving us to the research.

Comment: So often when dealing with government the requirement is to "meet current government policy" and they expect you to to tell them what that is! I guess that is why systems always cost the government twice as much as they would cost anyone else and still end up failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also have to comply with the Disability Discrimination act - especially as this is a Government resource.

Info on the act http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/DisabledPeople/RightsAndObligations/DisabilityRights/DG_4001068

and http://www.coi.gov.uk/guidance.php?page=169

And some information regarding websites and the act at http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-accessibility/uk-website-legal-requirements.shtml

and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accessuk

We deal with quite a few local councils and all of their sites must be accessible via screen readers so that those with visual impairments can use them, as such they need to be able to be navigated if the user has JavaScript and CSS disabled.

You need to ensure that if you use any CSS on the site that the navigation and structure degrade gracefully so that they make sense (e.g. don't make the navigation the last item on the page and then use CSS to move it to the top). Don't make any navigation dependant on Javascript either (or at least have an alternative method of navigating if the user has JavaScript turned off).

HTML and CSS should be validated to ensure there are no errors.

All images need ALT attributes

All links need title attributes

Any tables should have a summary

There are many more items like these but testing should flag these up.

In terms of testing the site, there are a few free screen readers available - although we had limited success with these as they were pretty hit and miss as to how they worked. "Jaws" seems to be the industry "standard" at the moment but this is ridiculously expensive so you may want to outsource any testing to another company; although some councils will organise this themselves.

You should also test the site on a text-only browser such as Lynx.

A few more resources can be found below:

Jaws http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp

Free http://www.screenreader.net, http://www.webaim.org/simulations/screenreader.php, http://www.xpscreenreader.com/

http://firevox.clcworld.net/ - Firefox plugin
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fangs/ - Firefox plugin

Accessibility Checkers

Functional Accessibility Evaluator - http://fae.cita.uiuc.edu/

WAVE - http://wave.webaim.org/
Cynthia Says - http://www.cynthiasays.com/

TAW Web Accessibility Test - http://www.tawdis.net/taw3/cms/en/

Or download the Firefox accessibility checker which contains checks for all the above as wells as HTML and CSS validators https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5809

Comment: A very helpful post and I'm sorry to nitpick, but...regarding nav menus and positioning within markup - surely this is okay provided there are links at the very beginning of the page that shortcut to the main areas (content, main nav etc.)? Obviously these links need to be implemented properly and visible on the page, adding display:none won't work (which unfortunately I've done many times!)

Comment: @Rory - Yes, that would work. I mentioned it as I have seen sites before that when CSS was turned off, the footer was at the top of the page and the main nav buried right at the bottom!

Comment: Lynxviewer: http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html is a good online screenreader.

Comment: Lynx is not a screenreader, it is a text-based browser, the two are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

You should firstly get the client to clarify these requirements, and make sure they actually research the subject as they may not currently have any idea about it and will just add the requirements further down the line when someone points it out (trust me, I've worked within a Scottish government organisation!)

Back when I worked in government (2004 - 2006), it was the e-Gov guidelines that were important and there was one on accessibility. I can't remember if these were publicly accessible or only available on an intranet, but I did find this page with what looks like the same documents: [Web Guidelines](http://www.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/government_it/web_guidelines.aspx). Again, you should clarify with the client what is the correct document to adhere to. They may also have their own accessibility standards, depending on what organisation they are (not that you can say of course, but I doubt one of the smaller councils is likely to have this).

The documents can be quite bland and hard to read, and often result in ugly websites because people believe simplicity is the only way to achieve accessibility. Of course this isn't true, so it's up to you to interpret the guidelines and provide justification for breaking them were necessary.

On the subject of tools, I assume you mean some kind of automated testing? If so, the answer is yes they exist, but please don't rely on them as your sole testing method! No amount of automated testing can ever tell you how truly accessible a website is, only real-world testing can do that. One place where a tool can come in handy however is checking colour contrast, there are several that will render your page using algorithms that emulate various forms of colour blindness.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different take on this one.

Why does jQuery / AJAX have to make the site less accessible?

Your page should work without any JavaScript and your jQuery and AJAX calls should be additional to the functionality of the page, replacing default behaviour where appropriate with "experience enhancing" features. One of the best elements of jQuery is that it helps you separate your JavaScript from your HTML.

On the accessibility front, I agree that you should be asking the client - but I also think that it should form a part of any project, even an internal administration console. Employers have to adhere to the rules in the disability discrimination act just as business-to-customer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to read the policy document for this published by the [Central Office of Information](http://www.coi.gov.uk/) (COI). [Delivering Inclusive Websites PDF](http://www.coi.gov.uk/documents/guidance/delivering-inclusive-websites.pdf)

To quote from the doc:

> These guidelines are for public sector
>   website owners and digital media
>   project managers wishing to deliver
>   inclusive, accessible websites. This
>   document sets out the minimum standard
>   of accessibility for public sector web
>   content and web authoring tools. It
>   recommends a user-centred approach to
>   accessibility, taking account of user
>   needs in the planning and procurement
>   phases of web design projects.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at out-law.com - a very good legal information site run by a law firm (Pinsent Masons). Their guide to accessibility and usability is here: http://www.out-law.com/page-337

The overview is good and in plain English, no legalese, and there is a section entitled "What standard is required?". It does make the point

> Testing your site against the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) is also a valuable indicator of accessibility.
>
> ...
>
> Conformance to WCAG should not be your primary goal and it certainly should not your only goal - but it is likely to be the first thing you check.

Each government department will have their own interpretation of minimum standard. I think there's a lot of inconsistency in some sites that are set up for government departments. As has been said by others - discuss this with the Client.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will generate accessible X/HTML mark-up for the client based entirely on the DOCTYPE you choose for the site and also the version of the web browser that is be used, which is a nice feature.

For public sector sites you need to try and ensure that an AJAX or JQuery elements are also available if JavaScript it disabled. That is, make the funky additional features an optional extra for JS-endowed users, but the core function of the page will work regardless.

Don't rely on JQuery for fundamental features as remember that in all liklihood, a screenreader will probably not be able to understand it and a non-JS browser won't either.

It's important to note that non-JS browser doesn't neccesarily mean an old browser, but could just mean a web browser on a device like a mobile phone or some other future device that we don't know about yet.

You should make sure that you use a DOCTYPE like XHTML 1.0 Strict. Specifying the DOCTYPE will mean that Visual Studio generates specific and compatible mark-up and 90% fullfills the requirement to create 'valid' code. You can check additional code quality with the W3C Validator Service.

For accesibility of content you should think about:

- Do the colour schemes I've used contrast sufficiently (for partially sighted users)
- Am I using clear and well-structured text in the pages (for blind users)
- Make use of the split between CSS and HTML and ensure that if CSS is disabled then the page renders in a reasonable fashion (of the very least looks like a screen reader could comprehend it).
- Make sure the code is valid using W3C Validators

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Visual Studio will generate accessible X/HTML mark-up" valid markup maybe, but no tool can know whether or not it is accessible, there are two many factors to determine that programmatically.

Comment: That is of course true, but "valid markup" is one of guidelines from WCAG 1.0 AA/P2 compliance:

"3.2 Create documents that validate to published formal grammars. [Priority 2]"

Getting this right is an absolute must and given that it requires no expert usability/accesibility knowledge to do it's a simple tick in the box prior to some of the more indepth tweaks required.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to have a straight forward answer as there isn't a lot of case law on this in the UK. Anyway, here is one resource:

http://www.rnib.org.uk/xpedio/groups/public/documents/PublicWebsite/public_legalcase.hcsp

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the contract, I wonder if the client shouldn't have input on that - called "requirements"?

W3C: [Web Accessibility Initiative](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) (WAI) may have some interesting points - in particular all the links from [Introduction to Web Accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php)

For tools to check, see [Complete List of Web Accessibility Evaluation Tools](http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/complete).

As long as you follow the intended *ehnance* approach of jQuery, it should be just as accessible as not

As an aside; you may find that ASP.NET MVC gives you more control over the html, and hence more ability to meet any requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [**Disability Discrimination Act**](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/DisabledPeople/RightsAndObligations/DisabilityRights/DG_4001068) (DDA).